# How can I programmatically back up my Blogger site?

Tags: blogger, backup

If you are logged in to your Blogger account, you can easily download a dump of your website by clicking on the Settings → Other → Export Blog link. ([Source](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97416).)

How can I do this automatically each day on Linux, from a cron job?

Comment: It’s not much, but take a look at [Blogger Backup](http://bloggerbackup.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screenshots&referringTitle=Home).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to do a login with curl and then you can simply invoke another call to the download link.

I would follow [this article](http://gdatatips.blogspot.co.il/2008/08/post-on-blogger-using-curl.html) to accomplish this. The trick is to find out which URL you need to call to export your blog.

What I did is:

1. Use Chrome
2. Open developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>).
3. Select the network tab.
4. Go to the "export" button/link and click it.

You will see the download happening, and you will see a new record in the network tab. Mine is : http://draft.blogger.com/feeds/7135654868651822450/archive (if not authenticated you will get 404).

[image]

**(update by Mark Harrison)** Based on the information above, here is a script that will download the xml dump of the blog. **(end update)**

```
FEED=12312312312312313
GMAIL=yourname@gmail.com

echo -n google passwd:
stty -echo
read GPASS
stty echo                  

AUTH=`curl 2>/dev/null https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin \
    -d Email=$GMAIL \   
    -d Passwd=$GPASS  \
    -d accountType=GOOGLE \
    -d source=blogix \
    -d service=blogger \
  | grep '^Auth=' | cut -c 6-`

curl >blog.xml \
    -H "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$AUTH" \
    http://www.blogger.com/feeds/$FEED/archive
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a 'cloud' solution, such as [backupify](http://backupify.com) or [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com/) ?

Answer (score 0):

As someone who uses Backupify, IFTTT, Zapier and a handful of other cloud connecting sites, I think in your case, a one time dump plus a IFTTT -> Dropbox for posts and files would be your best bet. To verify it's working, you could also have it send you an email with your post.

IFTTT has been around for years now and has always been reliable. They are planning on charging at some point, but I can't imagine you would fall under that for just this use case alone.

Backupify will charge you right off the bat.